# angular-cli and scss being inlined

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, angular-cli

I think i must be missing something very simple here.

Fresh install of angular-cli, create a new site with scss. Fill in the scss in the global style.scss and also some in a component scss.

when served or built those css are being inlined. They're not being externally included which is what i'd expect or need.

Also the component level scss cannot reference variables in the global style.scss (this is perhaps me expecting something else)

But how do i use scss to generated an external css file for delivery?

thanks!
Paul

Comment: Use loaders like `css.loader, style-loader` and `Extract-text-webpack-plugin` as angular-cli internally uses webpack.

Answer (score 1):

find `"styleExt": "css"` into angular-cli.json and replace with `"styleExt": "scss"`
 and then add "styles.scss" in "styles":[] into .angular-cli.json`

if you want to use scss in component use like  `styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']`

create one variable.scss for global variable and import in all other scss file.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
"server:dev": "ng serve -e dev --port 9000 --progress --watch --open --ec=true",
```

Adding '--ec=true' should do the trick.
Otherwise, you can eject your angular-cli app, and configure you webpack file manually, by adding more loaders.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject

Comment: I'm going to give that a go. I noticed however that if the app is bundled up for distribution then the styles do appear to be serve in separate files so i'm assuming this is a result of local serving in development.

What does ec mean?

thanks!

Comment: Yes, doing prod or an AOT build will extract styles out.
Same thing if you do --ec=true or --extract-css in dev, what it will do, is that it will extract your styles into separate files with their sourceMaps.
PS. We're not supposed to extract-css in dev, it makes the build veeeery slow (but for now this is the available solution.)
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4199

Comment: -- "Same thing if you do --ec=true or --extract-css in dev, what it will do, is that it will extract your styles into separate files with their sourceMaps."--

Not necessarily. Keep in mind that the --extract-css option only extracts the global css styles into stylesheets, not the component level styles. Whatever you have listed in the `styles` array in `.angular-cli.json` are the global styles.